# Does the intrinsic and extrinsic distances coincide on the interior?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, metric-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary. Consider the interior of $M$ (which we denote by $M^\circ$).

$M^\circ$ is an open submanifold of $M$. Let $d_M$ be the induced distance function (induced by the Riemannian metric on $M$ in the standard way), and let $d_{M^\circ}$ be the induced (intrinsic) distance on $M^\circ$. (Note that [$M^\circ$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107145/is-the-interior-of-a-smooth-manifold-with-boundary-connected) so it makes since to consider its intrinsic distance).

**Is it true that $d_M|_{M^\circ}=d_{M^\circ}$?**

(i.e does the intrinsic and extrinsic distances on $M^\circ$ coincide?)

---

I am pretty sure the answer is positive, since it seems reasonable that for every part of a path which lies on the boundary, we can perturb it a little bit so it will be inside the iterior, without increasing the length too much. (Similar to what is done in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379188/the-riemannian-distance-function-does-not-change-if-we-use-smooth-paths), for instance).

It would be nice to find an elegant argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short -- yes, just perturb the minimizing curve a bit. Below is a long version.

Let $p,q$ be two point in $M^o$, and let $\gamma$ be a length-minimizing geodesic between them (that may intersect the boundary). We want to show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\gamma_\epsilon$ between $p$ and $q$ such $\ell(\gamma_\epsilon)<\ell(\gamma) + \epsilon$.

By covering $M$ with a finite number of charts, the problem is reduced to modifying $\gamma$ in each coordinate chart. We don't need to modify $\gamma$ in charts where it does not hit the boundary, so let's consider one chart, modeled on $\mathbb{H}^n$ (that half space), with a metric $g_{ij}$, with $\gamma:[a,b]\to \mathbb{H}^n$ be a curve of finite length there. Assume further that $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ are not on the boundary (the argument can be easily adjusted if they do). Now $\gamma+(\delta,0,\ldots,0):[a,b]\to \mathbb{H}^n$ does not hit the boundary, and for $\delta>0$ small enough it is of length arbitrary close to the length of $\gamma$. Now, connect $\gamma(a)$ with $\gamma(a) + (\delta,0,\ldots,0)$ with a length minimizing geodesic. For small enough $\delta$ it does not hit the boundary, and the added length is arbitrarily small, resulting in a curve in the interior between $\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma(b)$ with length arbitrary close to that of $\gamma$.